# How can I export to CSV a custom output along with Module properties? [Powershell]

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, scripting

Here is my code, I am pulling user names, email addresses and a random password and would like to store these nicely in a CSV. How can I export to csv a custom property like my custom generated passwords while also exporting name and mail?

```
$pool = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Users,OU=funny,DC=Corp,DC=funny,DC=com"
foreach ($user in $pool )
{ 

    #MY NAME AND MAIL FUNCTION
    $a = Get-ADUser $user -Properties name, mail

    #MY PASSWORD FUNCTION
    $password = {blah,blah,blah}
    $password
}

$pool | Select-Object name,mail,$password | Export-Csv -path test.csv
```

How do I print the random password in the CSV along with name and mail?

Notes: I am doing this on AD. I would like the CSV to be neat as i will be parsing through it again using powershell. I am using Powershell 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the password as a NoteProperty in your foreach loop, using [Add-Member](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx) and then select on that.

So, something like this:

```
$pool = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=Test,OU=Users,OU=funny,DC=Corp,DC=funny,DC=com"
foreach ($user in $pool )
{ 

    #MY NAME AND MAIL FUNCTION
    $a = Get-ADUser $user -Properties name, mail

    #MY PASSWORD FUNCTION
    $password = {blah,blah,blah}
    $user | Add-Member -Force Password $password
    $password
}

$pool | Select-Object name,mail,Password | Export-Csv -path test.csv
```

Comment: The example above will work as above with Powershell 3 or above (I believe) - earlier version of PowerShell will not support the abbreviated version of Add-Member. You'll have to do something like `Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Password -Value $password`

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

But I had to add `-Force` to it because it gave me the following error.
`Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "Password" because a member with that name already exists. If you want to overwrite the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it.`

Might you know why this is? But i have solved it.

Comment: I added the `-Force` parameter to `Add-Member` in my answer, but that behaviour is interesting. I made a seperate question on Stack Overflow about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919541/why-does-add-member-think-every-possible-property-already-exists-on-a-microsoft

Comment: The question got an answer, the short answer is that the Active Directory objects are a bit "special", in that they do not behave like most other Powershell Objects. Hope that answers your query. :-)